# Qt Keyword are not recognized by VS2013?

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2013

I have pre-compiled binaries of Qt. I used the Qt plugin to incorporate it in my VS2013 IDE. I wrote a sample header file containing a `QObject`.

[image]

**PROBLEM:** The VS2013 does not recognize the Qt code. I have already correctly selected the path of binaries as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: `QObject` --> `Q_OBJECT` ?

Comment: @G.M. Thanks, it was typo but the problem is still the same.

Comment: It's still a typo.  Please read my comment again -- case is important.

Comment: @G.M yes, wrong picture was uploaded. I corrected it.

Comment: Since the build succeeded it looks like something is wrong with intellisense when you use the Qt addon. Looks like it does not use the include path of Qt. I do use Qt in Visual Studio 2013 but not the addon. I have not experienced this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the way the project was created. **I should have used the Qt Application to create the project** but I used the simple C++ console template to create the project and therefore, I was facing the issue.

[image]